# Android:: Version4.4 and below versions App crashing with VerifyError

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, verifyerror

I struggle with one issue in android. Earlier i developed an app along with android 4.4 and jdk6. Now i am going to upgrade same app in android 6 with jdk 7 for fingerprint authendication. Now the issue happen in android 4.4 and below versions app is crashing. It's throw verifyError. Any one help me out from this issue. 
IDE: eclipse. 
Note: I can't migrate android studio

```
`07-14 08:12:43.775: D/ActivityThread(18716): 
 handleBindApplication:sg.com.MyApp2u.MyApp
 07-14 08:12:43.775: D/ActivityThread(18716): 
 setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
 07-14 08:12:43.775: D/ActivityThread(18716): 
 setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
 07-14 08:12:44.035: W/dalvikvm(18716): VFY: unable to resolve 
 exception class 261 
 (Landroid/security/keystore/KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException;)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: W/dalvikvm(18716): VFY: unable to find exception 
 handler at addr 0x2a
 07-14 08:12:44.035: W/dalvikvm(18716): VFY:  rejected 
 Lsg/com/MyApp2u/MyApp/AppController;.cipherInit ()Z
 07-14 08:12:44.035: W/dalvikvm(18716): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d 
 at 0x002a
 07-14 08:12:44.035: W/dalvikvm(18716): VFY:  rejected 
 Lsg/com/MyApp2u/MyApp/AppController;.cipherInit ()Z
 07-14 08:12:44.035: W/dalvikvm(18716): Verifier rejected class 
 Lsg/com/MyApp2u/MyApp/AppController;
 07-14 08:12:44.035: D/AndroidRuntime(18716): Shutting down VM
 07-14 08:12:44.035: W/dalvikvm(18716): threadid=1: thread exiting 
 with uncaught exception (group=0x41d16d58)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716): Process: 
 sg.com.MyApp2u.MyApp, PID: 18716
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716): java.lang.VerifyError: 
 sg/com/MyApp2u/MyApp/AppController
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 sg.com.MyApp2u.MyApp.mobeix.onCreate(mobeix.java:170)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.app.Instrumentation.
 callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread. 
 performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread. 
 handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 com.android.internal.os.
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
 07-14 08:12:44.035: E/AndroidRuntime(18716):   at 
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried to use Multidex? i got some errors or crash on my app in android 4.4 if i don't use Multidex

Comment: I tried two ways:
1. paste android-support-multidex.jar file in ..\sdk\extras\android\support\multidex\library\libs 
clean and take build not working.

2. add multidex.jar file in workspace libs folder its also not working

still crash the application

Comment: You have to put this code `MultiDex.install(this);` in onCreate when your application starts for the first time. and put `multiDexEnabled true` in your gradle

Comment: yes i put MultiDex.install(this);  in my application class. and in manifest file i added android:name="com.maybank.test.AppController" but its not working